# Linux Source Routing with one gateway

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ip, routing

I've a Linux box which have IP 10.1.1.100/24 on eth0 with gateway 10.1.1.1 and as well as 20.1.1.1 on eth0:1 and 20.1.1.2 on eth0:2 . Is there any way that I could communicate to a remote machine having IP 192.168.1.1 using 20.1.1.1 or 20.1.1.2 ?

I've only one gateway and one physical interface to out my traffic however 20.1.1.2 is accessible from 192.168.1.1 but traffic out only from 10.1.1.100 when I try to communicate to 192.168.1.1 from my server.

Linux Box ( eth0 IP: 10.1.1.100 GW: 10.1.1.1 "eth0:1 20.1.1.2") ------- | Internet | ------ RemoteMachine ( eth0 IP: 192.168.1.1 )

in the above example I've public IPs on both local and remote machines so therefore remote machine can communicate to 20.1.1.2 using same gateway of 10.1.1.100 which is 10.1.1.1

I want to get some services from remote machine using IP 20.1.1.2 but when i try to communicate to remote machine IP 10.1.1.100 goes out to communicate to it.

Regards,

Comment: Can you give a rough network diagram of what you're doing?

Comment: any help please?